# Can an application find out information about currently playing song on iPhone/iPod Touch?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipod-touch

I've searched around a bit in the small amount of iPhone/iPod Touch development information available and couldn't find anything for or against.  Can an application find out information about currently playing song on iPhone/iPod Touch?  Since the music can continue to play while you are in 3rd party applications, is there a function or library that will give you information about what is playing? (Track, Artist, Album, etc.)  I know generally that applications are sand-boxed but thought maybe there was a way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you aren't planning to put your app on the App Store you can import MobileMusicPlayer.h as seen in this example application: [song-info](http://thebends.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/iphone-apps/music-player/song-info.c)

edit: Interacting with the iPod application is now part of the [iPhone OS 3.0 SDK](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 4):

Apple is pretty tight about allowing access to anything having to do with media (other than that provided by you) on the device. I've not found a way to do this.